# Click on popup to scroll

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I’m currently making an application in React, and i’m trying to scroll down the page, once I click a popup from a shape (tomtom maps SDK) I made on the map. Might sound confusing, but i’ll show you an example:

[Image of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKvwb.jpg)

So basically i’m trying to press the shape popup which says 52724743, and once i click that, it should scroll down to the menu with the corresponding code as you see below. However this doesn’t work. I’ll show you what I currently made:

```
this.popup = new tt.Popup({
        closeButton: false,
        closeOnClick: false,
        className: 'tt-popup -black',
        anchor: 'top'
    })
        .setLngLat(calculatePopupPosition(coordinates))
        .setHTML(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
            <>
            <a onClick={() => {
                const element = document.getElementById(id);
                element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})
            }}>{id}</a>
            </>
        ))
        .addTo(map);
```

I’ve also tried the following, which for some reason also doesn’t seem to work:

```
this.popup = new tt.Popup({
        closeButton: false,
        closeOnClick: false,
        className: 'tt-popup -black',
        anchor: 'top'
    })
        .setLngLat(calculatePopupPosition(coordinates))
        .setHTML(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
            <>
            <a href={"#" + id}></a>
            </>
        ))
        .addTo(map);
```

This is the id it should scroll to:

```
<>
    <div className="row m-3 p-4 block rounded" id={id}>
        <div className="col m-3 p-4">
            <h1>{id}</h1>
            <h3>Gebiedsgrootte: {GebiedsGrootte}</h3>
            <h3>Geselecteerde locaties: {puntenlengte}</h3>
            <h3>Geselecteerde containers: {containerteller}</h3>

            <div id={"Reistijd" + id}>
            {Reistijden.map(x => (
              <h3 key={x.wagensoort + x.traveltime}>Reistijd {x.wagensoort}: {x.traveltime}</h3>
        ))}
          </div>
            <select className="form-select" name="wagen" id={"wagen" + id} onChange={this.functie} ref={selectRef}>
              <option value={"Kies een optie"}>Kies een optie</option>
              {wagenpark.map(x => (
                <>
                <option key={x.wagensoort} id={x.wagensoort} value={x.wagensoort}>{x.wagensoort}</option>
                </>
              ))}
            </select>
            <br></br>

              <div className="row">
                <div className="col">
                <select className="form-select" name="xPerWeek" id={"xPerWeek" + id} onChange={() => this.xPerWeek("xpw")} ref={this.xpWeek}>
              <option value={0}>X Keer per week</option>
              <option value={1}>1</option>
              <option value={2}>2</option>
              <option value={3}>3</option>
              <option value={4}>4</option>
              <option value={5}>5</option>
              <option value={6}>6</option>
              <option value={7}>7</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div className="col">
            <select className="form-select" name="inXWeken" id={"inXWeken" + id} onChange={() => this.xPerWeek("ixw")} ref={this.iXWeek}>
              <option value={0}>Per X Weken</option>
              <option value={1}>1</option>
              <option value={2}>2</option>
              <option value={3}>3</option>
              <option value={4}>4</option>
              <option value={5}>5</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div className="col">
            <select className="form-select" name="Dagen" id={"Dagen" + id} onChange={()=> this.xPerWeek("dag")} ref={this.dagen}>
              <option value={0}>Op dag x</option>
              <option value={"Maandag"}>Maandag</option>
              <option value={"Dinsdag"}>Dinsdag</option>
              <option value={"Woensdag"}>Woensdag</option>
              <option value={"Donderdag"}>Donderdag</option>
              <option value={"Vrijdag"}>Vrijdag</option>
              <option value={"Zaterdag"}>Zaterdag</option>
              <option value={"Zondag"}>Zondag</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={this.reset}>Reset</button>
            </div>

            <h3>{tekst}</h3>
            <h3>Afstand: {kilometers}</h3>

            <div className="dropdown">
            <button onClick={this.myFunction} className="dropbtn">Adressen</button>
            <div id={"myDropdown" + id} className="dropdown-content">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id={"myInput" + id} className="myInput" ref={input} onKeyUp={this.filterFunction}/>
                {punten.map(element => (
                <h4 key={element.id} className="blockformenu">{element.straat} {element.huisnummer}, {element.postcode.split(",")[0]} {element.plaats}</h4>
                ))}
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        <div className="col m-3 p-4">
        <input placeholder="Naam" ref={myRef}></input>
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.submit}>Klik hier om op te slaan</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </>
```

Can somebody help me out with what i’m doing wrong?

Comment: As a fellow dutchman, Oelewapper was the first thing I saw haha. But if I understand correctly, when you press the square, it should scroll down and fill the value in the input? 

Are you gettting any error's?

Comment: Let me explain: Once you press the code as seen on the map, you should automatically scroll to the corresponding details, as seen below. However, since TomTom mostly uses InnerHTML, which is incompatable with React, i'm not quite sure what the solution to this one is. I'm not getting a single error